# creating migrations for NestJS with Mikro-orm and NX monorepo error: MetadataError: No entities were discovered

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm, nx-monorepo

I have tried to set up mikroORM in my mono repo project and faced the main problem. That follows the idea with one package.json I didn't find any other ways how to make connections in microservices to DB.
So I created in lib DB connector with dynamic module registry like:

```
export class DbConnectorModule {
  static register(config: Options<PostgreSqlDriver>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DbConnectorModule,
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
        MikroOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: () => ({
            ...config
          }),
          inject: [ConfigService],
        } as MikroOrmModuleAsyncOptions),
      ],
      exports: [MikroOrmModule],
    };
  }
}
```

then in my microservice, in root directory I added mikro-orm.config.ts:

```
const mikroOrmConfig: Options<PostgreSqlDriver> = {
  baseDir: join(__dirname, '..'),
  type: 'postgresql',
  allowGlobalContext: true,
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
  dbName: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  entities: ['./dist/domains/**/entities/*.entity.js'],
  entitiesTs: ['./src/domains/**/entities/*.entity.ts'],
  highlighter: new SqlHighlighter(),
  debug: true,
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'migrations',
    path: './dist/migrations',
    pathTs: './src/migrations',
    glob: '!(*.d).{js,ts}',
    emit: 'ts',
    snapshot: false,
    generator: TSMigrationGenerator,
  },

};
```

so the idea is that every microservice will own its independent config and module registry like:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: './apps/open-banking/.env',
      validationSchema: Joi.object(
        {
          POSTGRES_URI: Joi.string().required(),
          SALTEDGE_APP_ID: Joi.string().required(),
          SALTEDGE_APP_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
          SALTEDGE_REDIRECT_LINK: Joi.string().required(),
          DATABASE_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
          DATABASE_PORT: Joi.string().required(),
          DATABASE_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
          DATABASE_USER: Joi.string().required(),
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: Joi.string().required()
        }
      )
    }),
    HealthCheckModule.register(),
    DbConnectorModule.register(mikroOrmConfig)
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: []
})
```

but in a result, I receive an error message that my config can't find any entities when I try to run my microservice or run init for migration.

````
[Nest] 4599  - 06/05/2023, 11:31:26 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No entities were discovered ```
````

When I temporarily put in the config file for
`entities` and `entitiesTs` class of entity the error is gone:

```
entities: [ProfileEntity],
  entitiesTs: [ProfileEntity]
```

But anyway it does not work for running migrations through CLI. So maybe anybody could help or faced with same case